# Issue returning result from a function

Tags: javascript, object

Hi I cannot return information from a function? When I try I always receive an 'undefined' message.

When I console.log the variables within the function the information appears to be correct.

The purpose of the function is to add sales data for an employee to the employee object.

This is what should happen -

```
{
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Jones',
    gender: 'Non-Binary',
    age: 54,
    position: 'Salesperson',
    sales: [{
            staffId: 3,
            item: 'Pre-built PC',
            price: 1999.95,
            date: '02-09-2022'
        },
        {
            staffId: 3,
            item: 'USB Cable',
            price: 5,
            date: '02-09-2022'
        },
        {
            staffId: 3,
            item: 'HDMI Cable',
            price: 15.45,
            date: '02-09-2022'
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the function that I have -

```
function mapEmpAndSales() {
    employeesData.map(function(employee) {
        let newEmpInfo = Object.assign({}, employee);
        // console.log("1");
        // console.log(newEmpInfo.id);
        newEmpInfo.sales = salesData.filter(function(element) {
            return element.staffId == employee.id;
        });
        // console.log("2");
        // console.log("XXXXXXXX");
        // console.log(newEmpInfo);
        return newEmpInfo;
        // result = newEmpInfo;
    });
    // console.log(result);
    // return result;
}
const finalresult = mapEmpAndSales();
// let newInfo = mapEmpAndSales();
console.log("XXXXXXX");
console.log(finalresult);
```

Comment: You don’t use return directly in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
// return result;
```

is necessary to pass data back out through your function. It should not be commented out. But I don't think you want to return result, rather return employeesData variable.

```
return employeesData;
```

Comment: Sorry new to JS and trying to understand so sorry if this is wrong. With that filter line I am trying to say that if the staff id = employee id add that to the object and set it through  employee.sale 
If you console log on newEmpInfo it returns correctly as shown  above with what should happen.

Comment: That works. Thanks so much. Would the employeeData variable returned overwrite the original data ?

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you aren't returning in the function *'mapEmpAndSales'*, if you see your return is inside the *'function(employee){...}'*. So, you create this function *'function(employee)'* and return in that, but in the body of your main function have no return.

Try creating a const outside the map function like *'const result = []'*, and in your map function you add the result at it and in your main function your really return the result.

Like this:

```
function mapEmpAndSales() {
    const result = [];
    employeesData.map(function(employee) {
        let newEmpInfo = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, employee));
        newEmpInfo.sales = salesData.filter(function(element) {
            return element.staffId == employee.id;
        });
        result.push(...newEmpInfo); // IF IT RETURNS A ARRAY
        result.push(newEmpInfo); //IF IT RETURNS ONLY ONE VALUE
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapEmpAndSales` didn't return any thing, you need return the value of `employeesData.map(...)`.

```js
function mapEmpAndSales() {
    return employeesData.map(function(employee) {
        // ....
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function returns an array, which should be captured ad returned from the `mapEmpAndSales` function.

The solution is already in your code, just simply uncommenting the `//return result;` line as the following:

```
function mapEmpAndSales() {
    let result = employeesData.map(function(employee) {
        let newEmpInfo = Object.assign({}, employee);
        newEmpInfo.sales = salesData.filter(function(element) {
            return element.staffId == employee.id;
        });
        return newEmpInfo;
    });
    return result;
}
const finalresult = mapEmpAndSales();
console.log(finalresult);
```